# How to display a screen which contains of an Icon on top half and ListView on bottom half?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display a mock-up streaming screen like this:

[image]

Top half is the video player (showing the speaker), and bottom half is a ListView displaying participants/subscribers list.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'common.dart';

class StreamingView extends StatelessWidget {

  
  // Display a Participant item
  Widget getParticipantView(Participant item) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                item.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }


  // Display the participants list on a ListView
   Widget getParticipantsListView(List<Participant> participantsList){
    //@override
   // Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container (
       //Expanded()
       height: 40,
       child: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: participantsList.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return getParticipantView(participantsList[index]);
         }
       )
     );
  //}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {

    List<Participant> theList = [
      Participant(name: "Jack", description:"Away"), 
      Participant(name:"Paul", description:"Available"),
      Participant(name:"Clive", description:"Available"), 
      Participant(name:"Frank", description:"Available")
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Image.asset('assets/generic_portrait.jpg'),

                 Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: getParticipantsListView(theList)
                  ),

              ],
            )),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              print("The button is clicked...");

            },
            child: Icon(Icons.video_call)));
  }
}
```

I ran it, and the result is this:

[image]

The speaker can be seen, but the participants list isn't. Turns out there's an exception:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
> ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex
> children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are
> unbounded. When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite
> height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it
> will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting
> a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to
> expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These
> two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap
> its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent. ... ... The relevant error-causing
> widget was:   Column
> file:///C:/Users/anta40/Flutter/streamingtest/streaming.dart:11:16

That refers to `child: Column(` inside `Widget getParticipantView()`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use stack , the parent maybe use column after that the stack will be the first , after that use a listview which can hold all the participants

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Shrink-wrap in ListView.builder and remove the container with Static height.

Answer (score 0):

The hight is unbound because you're using `Expanded` widget in the column. Remove the `Expanded` widget that is wrapping the `CircleAvatar`. Here's your code:

```
// Display a Participant item
Widget getParticipantView(Participant item) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                item.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          ],
        ));
  }
```